# Undelete a question of a deleted user

Tags: support, vote-to-undelete

Due to the [recent deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40308854/timeline) of a user, [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40308854) got deleted too.  Unfortunately, this question contains three valuable answers & comments.

As far as I understand [previous requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314154/request-to-undelete-a-question), this is the procedure to get it undeleted.

Comment: You need +20k rep to do so.

Comment: It's undeleted now.  You've also cast an undelete vote on it, so you did your part.

Comment: Anyone thinks that those answers would be better off on another question?

Comment: Welcome to meta-effect!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the future, you can also flag a moderator for this using a custom flag on that post (or a random post with a link to the question to be undeleted). It's generally pretty easy for us to evaluate if there are answers worth saving and thus whether we should undelete the question.

Sometimes people use account deletions like this to circumvent us declining to delete their questions, or there's collateral damage from us cleaning up sock puppets or question-ban evaders. If there's value in the answers, I don't mind being made aware of that.